# Play cannot reference external javascript

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, server

**A very basic question**

Cannot load external javascript resource on server 
I am working on a Play framework project. I've made some basic html view with some Javascript. It works correctlly when I have my js code in the actual view.
However, when I tried moving js code to a separate file and load it using

```
<script> src="main.js" </script>
```

It works correctly when opened using plain chrome browser. However when I run it on server and it fails and chrome dev console prints the following message

> GET http://localhost:9000/main.js 404 (Not Found)

I've tried setting up a GET request on targer URL but cannot pass main.js as an arguement to Ok method

```
def getmainJs()= Action {
    Ok()
  }
```

Is there a painless way to access the js code or do I have to go through the process of setting up the JavacriptRouter menntioned here. The app is only going to be 2 views to I kind of don't care about scalability

Comment: Please check this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AssetsOverview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an [example](https://github.com/ygor-sk/stackoverflow/tree/master/q53319493-javascript-asset) on how to serve a Javascript file:

Routes:

```
GET         /foo                 sk.ygor.stackoverflow.q53319493.controller.ApplicationController.foo
GET         /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.versioned(file)
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("main.js")"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had to inject assets Finder to the Controller I was using and it worked. Thank you for help. Cheers!